# Posterior covariance of the function values and derivatives of a Gaussian Process

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix, gaussian-process, constrained-regression, kriging

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the cross-terms of the covariance matrix between the function values and derivatives of a Gaussian Process. For context, this is needed for Gaussian Process regression with positivity and monotonicity constraints, where the derivative and/or function values are constrained (see [Da Veiga and Marrel 2020](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01515468)).

Specifically, this means calculating the posterior (predictive) covariance between the function values and derivative at a set of 'constraint points' $X_z$:
$$\mathrm{Cov}(f(X_z), \frac{\partial f(X_z)}{\partial x}) $$

So far I have found [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/475076/covariance-of-derivative-of-gaussian-process-regression) (which references a pdf written by [McHutchon](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/mchutchon/DifferentiatingGPs.pdf) for which the URL is now broken) for calculating the variance of the derivative of the Gaussian Process $\mathrm{Cov}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x})$, but I've struggled to derive any expression for the combined covariance of $f(x)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$

Comment: See section 9.4 of GP4ML https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW9.pdf

Comment: @jcken Thanks, but that only gives the expression for the *prior* covariance of the function values with the derivatives, not the *posterior*. I have to condition the GP on given data points X_s (more specifically, calculate Cov(f, df/dx | f(X_s) = f_s)

Comment: You can just apply the standard GP posterior variance; $var(A|B) = var(A) - cov(A, B) var(B)^{-1} cov(B, A)$. Use $A = (f, \frac{df}{dx})$, $B  = f(X_s)$.  Then $Cov(f, \frax{df}{dx} | f(X_s)$, the posterior covariance, would then be read off as a `corner' (upper right block)of $var(A|B)$