# Gradient of Gaussian Process Regressor

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, matrix, gradient

I have a data ((x,y),f) that I am fitting using Gaussian Process Regression in Python's sklearn package. The posterior mean of the GP is essentially my output with an associated error. Based on either the posterior mean or the original data itself, is there a way to calculate gradients of the original data via GP?
x and y are features. This is not a 1D problem. Can someone suggest me a 2D solution.

I am trying to solve a 2D Non-Linear Poisson's Equation. I need the values of both prediction and gradient to solve this.

Comment: What do you need the gradients for?

Comment: I am trying to solve a 2D Non-Linear Poisson's Equation. I need the values of both prediction and gradient to solve this.

Comment: check section 9.4 of R&W (https://gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf) for a very brief description

Comment: Related/answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180823/derivative-of-a-gaussian-process)